# Google script for moving row along with data to another sheet according to a cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can anyone help me/give me a google sheet script for this function? What I'd like to happen is that whenever I change the application status of the candidates to "hired" the candidate along with its data and formatting in the row will automatically be transferred to a different sheet - "HIRED" in the sample sheet. Ang all other data will be left in the present sheet - "LIST" - if their status is not changed to hire.

Here's a copy of my Google Sheet. Hope you can help me with this. Thank you so much!

[image]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XFQSv3lNTnC3ExbOjbk8Gi9Tvk5wuX6kNwtmOJ_qm7M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Is your showing image the sample input situation? If my understanding is correct, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample output situations you expect as an image?

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I've understood, you want to move the candidate row from **LIST** sheet to **HIRED** sheet  whenever the **Application Status** is changed to **HIRED**. This can be done using onEdit Trigger.

### Try this:

**Code:**

```
function moveHired(e){
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var col = range.getColumn();
  var value = e.value;

  var hiredSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("HIRED");
  var hsLastRow = hiredSheet.getLastRow();
  
  if(sheet.getName() == "LIST" && col == 2 && row > 1 && value == "HIRED"){
    sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 10).copyTo(hiredSheet.getRange(hsLastRow+1, 1, 1, 10));
    sheet.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

**Trigger Setup:**

[image]

**Demo:**

[image]

### References:

- [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)
- [Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: Hi! I'm glad you understand my question. I tried the code you giveand there's an error that says "e.range undefined" for line 2. When I tested it nothing happened. I have another code/script for sorting saved for this sheet. Do you think there could be a conflict between my sorting code and your code?